# Castle Windsor - How can I register an interface that implements an interface with generics to a class with generics?

Tags: c#, generics, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, decorator

Given the code below, How do I set up the registrations in Castle Windsor (latest version) to make ISomeService resolve to SomeDecorator< SomeRequest, SomeResponse>?

```
public interface IService<in TRequest, out TResponse>
{
    TResponse Get(TRequest request);
}

public class SomeRequest
{
    public int SomeId { get; set; }
    public int SomeOtherId { get; set; }
}

public class SomeResponse
{
    public int SomeId { get; set; }
    public string SomeName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> SomeList { get; set; }
}

public interface ISomeService : IService<SomeRequest, SomeResponse> { }

public class SomeService : ISomeService
{
    public SomeResponse Get(SomeRequest request)
    {
        return new SomeResponse { SomeId = request.SomeId, SomeName = "The Name", SomeList = new List<string>() };
    }
}

public class SomeDecorator<TRequest, TResponse> : IService<TRequest, TResponse>
{
    private readonly IService<TRequest, TResponse> _service;

    public SomeDecorator(IService<TRequest, TResponse> service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    public TResponse Get(TRequest request)
    {
        //Do something before
        var response = _service.Get(request);
        //Do something after
        return response;
    }
}
```

With the following registrations, ISomeService is resolving to SomeService, not SomeDecorator
< SomeRequest, SomeResponse>

```
public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
{
    container.Register(Component
        .For(IService<SomeRequest,SomeResponse>)
        .ImplementedBy(ISomeService));
    container.Register(Component
        .For(ISomeService)
        .ImplementedBy(SomeService));
    container.Register(Component
        .For(IService<,>)
        .ImplementedBy(SomeDecorator<,>)
        .IsDefault());
}
```

When I try to register ISomeService to be implemented by SomeDecorator< SomeRequest, SomeResponse>, I get the following error message:

> Unable to cast object of type 'SomeDecorator`2[SomeRequest,SomeResponse]' to type 'ISomeService'.

Comment: SomeDecorator doesn't implement the interface ISomeService, so the message is correct; perhaps you'd better try and resolve the correct interface?

Comment: I have multiple service interfaces: ISomeService, IOtherService, IAnotherService, which all implement IService<,> (each with their specific request/response pairs). I can't have SomeDecorator implementing each of these services because that will force me to implement the Get function specifically for each type. I want to use the generic Get within the Decorator for any IService that's implemented. I think I may be trying to do something that's not possible.

Comment: I think that there is a better way to do what you want. Try using a topped factory to resolve your generic types at runtime. Have a look at my questions about them for example.

Comment: @Lisa.Filemyr see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637216/how-can-i-register-a-generic-decorator-using-castle-windsor) for some useful information. Also, IMO, you don't need `ISomeService` - you can simplify your design with `public class SomeService : IService<SomeRequest, SomeResponse>`

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to get it working. The downside of this solution is that you have to register the decorator against each class you want to decorate.

As I said in my comment above you can simplify your design by getting rid of `ISomeService` and go with `public class SomeService : IService<SomeRequest, SomeResponse>` instead. The registration for the decorator then looks like this:

```
container.Register(
    Component.For<IService<SomeRequest, SomeResponse>>()
        .ImplementedBy<SomeDecorator<SomeRequest, SomeResponse>>(),
    Component.For<IService<SomeRequest, SomeResponse>>()
        .ImplementedBy<SomeService>());
```

Also note you could automate the registration of all your generic implementations with LINQ queries.