# Is there a way to explicitly register open generic decorators with castle windsor

Tags: castle-windsor, simple-injector

I use castle windsor a lot in a project i'm working on and use decorators a little so I might have something like this in my installer

```
Component.For<IMyViewModelService>().ImplementedBy<MyViewModelServiceCacheDecorator>().LifestyleTransient()
Component.For<IMyViewModelService>().ImplementedBy<MyViewModelService>().LifestyleTransient()
```

So doing this is easy enough and works well. I started reading around the simple injector framework and I really like they way you can specifically set the decorators on open generics when using the command pattern.

https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced.html#decorators

Does castle windsor have any functionality that allows you to do the same thing in this declarative manner?  I'm using castle windsor 3.3 and always stay with the latest.

I see this question which is kind of similar but doesn't have a full outcome
[registering open generic decorators for typed implementations in castle windsor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17087489/registering-open-generic-decorators-for-typed-implementations-in-castle-windsor)

Comment: I've read multiple question on Stackoverflow about generic decorators with Castle ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26387133), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24084504/), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17087489)), and Castle still seems to have no good support for this and they recommend interceptors instead (yuck!!). However, the last answer I could found from Krzysztof Kozmic [dates back to September 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637216/how-can-i-register-a-generic-decorator-using-castle-windsor), so I'm not sure this is still accurate.

Comment: But if Simple Injector supports your architecture,  but Castle does not, why stick with Castle?

Comment: Very good point, too big an effort to change at this point in the project, getting buy in for a change that would probably take 2-3 man days I'm not sure I could swing.  It does give me loads of ammo for saying we shouldn't use Castle for future projects.  For the record I like your Simple Injector a lot more, docs are awesome too!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm not understanding what you're trying to do, but Castle supports open generic decorators just fine.  Given these objects:

```cs
public interface IService<T>
{
    void Info();
}

public class Service<T> : IService<T>
{
    public void Info()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetType());
    }
}

public class ServiceDecorator<T> : IService<T>
{
    readonly IService<T> service;

    public ServiceDecorator(IService<T> service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public void Info()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetType());
        service.Info();
    }
}
```

And this registration and resolution:

```cs
container.Register(Component.For(typeof(IService<>)).ImplementedBy(typeof(ServiceDecorator<>)));
container.Register(Component.For(typeof(IService<>)).ImplementedBy(typeof(Service<>)));
```

Then resolving the service and calling `Info`:

```cs
IService<int> service = container.Resolve<IService<int>>();
service.Info();
```

Will print:

```
Sample.ServiceDecorator`1[System.Int32]
Sample.Service`1[System.Int32]
```

If this *is not* what you're trying to do, please update your question with a more precise example.

Comment: Fair enough, I wouldn't say this is explicitly says - decorate this with that however it is the behavior I want.

Comment: But wrapping an open generic implementation with an open generic decorator is not a very common use case. You usually have non-generic implementations of some generic interface and want to wrap that with an open generic decorator. Can you show how to do that?

Comment: I explicitly ask about non-generic implementations, because in that case your example will fail. @Neil, are you sure that Patrick's example is the behavior you need?

Comment: Good point, I'm trying to build myself a little example at the moment here at https://github.com/bapti/CastleExamples - I would like to be able to have decorators that target specific command handlers and also decorators that target all command handlers. Hopefully I'll get some time this afternoon and I can create a failing or passing test

Comment: @Steven - I've updated the command pattern example, as you say I don't think it will be possible to get the behaviour the test describes at https://github.com/bapti/CastleExamples/blob/master/src/CommandPattern.Tests/CommandPatternTests.cs - I'll add some more cases too