# Windsor - decorate all found implementations

Tags: c#, decorator, castle-windsor

I have an interface for getting data, `IGetter<IEvent>`, which has several implementations (each for getting data from other type of source). This interface is generic, because its implementations can return different kind of events (`SourceEvent` and `StatisticsEvent`, both based on `IEvent` interface, however).

Here's a sample code (with hidden details to make the post shorter - full working demo for LINQPad is [here](http://share.linqpad.net/llanl8.linq)). The decorators are being registered, but not resolved. Only plain `Getters` are resolved, without logging and caching capabilities.

How should I register this code for decorators to work?

```
// An interface defining an event, "something happened at time When"
public interface IEvent { DateTime When { get; set; }}
// They come from a number of sources (e.g. Windows Event Log, sent e-Mails, disk activity, actions logged in issue tracker etc.)
public class SourceEvent     : IEvent { public DateTime When { get; set; } public string What { get; set; }}
// Some implementations:
public class MailEvent       : SourceEvent { }
public class FileEvent       : SourceEvent { }
// List of all events returned from all implemented sources will be ultimately calculated into activity level at any given time
public class StatisticsEvent : IEvent { public DateTime When { get; set; } public int HowMany{ get; set; }}


// An interface for a class capable of reading IEvents from one source
public interface IGetter<TData> where TData : IEvent { /*...*/ }
// Some implementations
public class MailGetter       : IGetter<MailEvent> { /*...*/ }
public class FileGetter       : IGetter<FileEvent> { /*...*/ }
// Implementation of this is also based on IGetter (but it gets data from all other IGetters - simplified in this example)
public class StatisticsGetter : IGetter<StatisticsEvent> { /*...*/ }


// Decorators for IGetters - all the magical things I want Getters to be able do
public class Cache<TData>  : IGetter<TData> where TData : IEvent { /*...*/ }
public class Logger<TData> : IGetter<TData> where TData : IEvent { /*...*/ }


void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Dependency Injection registration
    var ioc = new WindsorContainer();
    ioc.Register(
        Component.For(typeof(IGetter<>)).ImplementedBy(typeof(Cache<>)),
        Component.For(typeof(IGetter<>)).ImplementedBy(typeof(Logger<>)), // Decorators registered here are not being injected
        Classes.FromThisAssembly()
            .BasedOn(typeof(IGetter<>))
            .WithServiceBase() // Getters for all sources are registered fine
    );

    var source1 = ioc.Resolve<IGetter<MailEvent>>();
    source1.Query().Dump("Source 1 - \"Querying mails\"");
    source1.Query().Dump("Source 1 - \"From cache\""); // Doesn't read from cache, instead it queries again

    var source2 = ioc.Resolve<IGetter<FileEvent>>();
    source2.Query().Dump("Source 2 - \"Querying files\"");
    source2.Query().Dump("Source 2 - \"From cache\"");

    var stats = ioc.Resolve<IGetter<StatisticsEvent>>(); // All implementations of IGetter and all implementations of IEvent must be successfully resovled
    stats.Query().Dump("Statistics - \"Querying stats\"");
    stats.Query().Dump("Statistics - \"From cache\"");

//  This works, but we need Windsor to do it for us
    //  var manual = new Cache<MailEvent>(new Logger<MailEvent>(new MailGetter()));
    //  manual.Query().Dump("Manual - \"Querying mails\"");
    //  manual.Query().Dump("Manual - \"From cache\"");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running into the rather opinionated way Castle Windsor determines the order and priority of resolving dependencies.

Because you have an open generic registration, or rather you have two, but also a raft of concrete type registrations, it will give priority to the concrete implementations.

There are several trains of thought around how to solve this.

**Manual Explicit Registration of all generic type decorators**

```
ioc.Register(
    Component.For<IGetter<MailEvent>>().ImplementedBy<Logger<MailEvent>>(),
    Component.For<IGetter<FileEvent>>().ImplementedBy<Logger<FileEvent>>(),
    Component.For<IGetter<StatisticsEvent>>().ImplementedBy<Logger<StatisticsEvent>>(),

    Component.For<IGetter<MailEvent>>().ImplementedBy<Cache<MailEvent>>(),
    Component.For<IGetter<FileEvent>>().ImplementedBy<Cache<FileEvent>>(),
    Component.For<IGetter<StatisticsEvent>>().ImplementedBy<Cache<StatisticsEvent>>(),

    Classes.FromThisAssembly()
                       .BasedOn(typeof(IGetter<>))
                       .WithServiceBase() // Getters for all sources are registered fine
            );
```

The drawback is that it becomes very easy to forget to register another decorator, but it will do the trick.

**Interceptors (as per their [documentation](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/interceptors.md))**
Your mileage may vary with these, as these effectively proxy your implementations and act before or after their executions. They kinda act like decorators but not in the pure sense of them.

**Handroll an implementation of an `ISubDependencyResolver`**, as per the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637216/how-can-i-register-a-generic-decorator-using-castle-windsor).

Comment: After some time to think about, I decided that verbose manual registration in my case is the least evil thing to do.